# Design considerations when adding a "Sign in with Facebook" button

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

- Where is the best place to place the **Sign in with Facebook**
  button?
- Is it even necessary to place it on the splash, login and signup
  screens?

I've been working on a mobile application, and would like to know the best design practices when placing this button on the splash, login and signup screens. What considerations do I need to make to in order to not disrupt the overall UX experience?

### **Splash screen**

[image]

### **Sign up screen**

[image]

### **Login screen**

[image]

Comment: You can have a look on practices by some major companies: [Log In Screenshots: Mobile Patterns](http://www.mobile-patterns.com/log-in), [iOS Log on screen patterns](http://pttrns.com/categories/12-logins) and [Tablet Patterns](http://morepttrns.com/). You can also search it on Pinterest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

signing in/up with facebook is used as a utility to ease the "daunting" task of onboarding, getting the user into your app quicker and with ease. with that said - there are two strategies that can be done-

1. having the facebook button accessible landing screen. this can double as logging in or signing up - then leading the user to your "Sign Up" page with their facebook credentials (and even profile picture) filled out on the form.
2. Having the landing page focus specifically on sign-up - with two buttons leading to the Sign Up form, one button for `Sign Up With Facebook`, another with `Sign up with Email`- along with a login button on the bottom. Having a sign up - specific landing page is beneficial because it put's new users front and center, and also because most of the time users do not log out(although there is still a way to log in). Another benefit with this is that if you decide to support signing up with another network (i.e. `Sign in with Twitter` `Sign in with Google)` you can add it to the landing page

Answer (score 0):

in 1st screen : You can add Sign-Up-with-Facebook button below the login one having the size of both the buttons. 
**OR** 
You can change the size of the current buttons and make it of the same size by placing them vertically one after another. 
**OR**  *It can be managed like this done on tumblr*
[image: IT can be managed like this done on tumblr]